# How to save a dataset table using a button?

Tags: c#, save

I have a group of data sets and they are all editable, what I need is a function that copies all of the information in the data tables and saves it back into the data set or as a seperate xml.

Comment: @barrick Some google searches, I'm relatively new to coding so a lot of things are unclear.

Comment: A DataTable is not an immutable object; that is, it can be updated programatically, so there's no need to create a copy and save that instead. In what sort of environment are they being updated - is it a web UI, all in memory etc..?

Comment: @barrick, it's through a server. They are being uploaded through a server and then you can edit the value such as "Entity Name" from null to a name

Comment: Sorry, don't think I was clear there. Where does, for example, the Entity Name come from? Is this user input from a web page, read in from a console application etc?

Comment: @barrick A webpage but the webpage is inaccessible from the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, a `DataTable` is updatable. I can write

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] = "Test"
```

(where ds is a `DataSet`) and that will update row 1, column 1 of the first `DataTable` within the `DataSet`. What I do from there with it is my choice, but the change is there **in the in-memory copy of the DataSet**.

If you're populating from a database via a `DataAdapter`, you can then call `Update()` to commit the changes back to the database, but if you're not in that scenario, then your change will remain in memory until you either dispose of the DataSet/s or go back off to the source to fetch them again.

I think the bottom line here is that you don't need a function to update DataTables, as they are inherently capable of being updated.